# Android Exoplayer can't open asset audio file

Tags: android, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I try to play a local audio file (.mp3) from androids `assets` folder with exoplayer.

I used the following code for test purposes:

```
val uri = Uri.fromFile(File("//assets/iron_maiden_fear_of_the_dark.mp3"))
println("$uri")  --> file:///assets/iron_maiden_fear_of_the_dark.mp3
```

Now I try to create a exoplayer AssetDataSource:

```
val dataSpec = DataSpec(uri)
val assetDataSource = AssetDataSource(this)
assetDataSource.open(dataSpec)
```

And that throws an Exception:

```
com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.AssetDataSource$AssetDataSourceException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: assets/iron_maiden_fear_of_the_dark.mp3
```

I don't know why?

Comment: I think you need the full file path.

Comment: No, doesn't make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by using a `RawResourceDataSource` for File in `res/raw` Folder.